# Sql return multiple rows with same check_id and group by similar ref_no

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure.

```
 check_id     name     ref_no

 10          alsak     xdr
 21          turin     xdr
 10          tend      ymt
 21          turin     kuy
```

Now i want to return records matching a certain `check_id` with similar ref_no
An example with 10 and 21 since they have xdr.

So in my query i have

```
SELECT * FROM `turip_refs` WHERE `check_id`=10 OR `check_id`=21
```

In the above it returns all records with id of 10 and 21. How do i modify this to also group by ref_no and only return records with a matching ref_no with the set check_id on the query.

Comment: Did you try using DISTINCT?

Comment: @Geoff . . . You question is not clear, partly because your example is so simple and you don't show your desired results.  Do you want *rows* from t he original data?  Or just `ref_no`s?  Do you want repeats that are just twice?  Or all of them?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i would like this to happen in all instances matching the criteria of the set check_id and having a similar ref_no. The return should be all the row records that is check_id,name and ref_no. I hope its now clear.

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
select ref_no
from turip_refs
where check_id in (10, 21)
group by ref_no
having count(distinct check_id) = 2
```

you get all the `ref_no`s which have a row with `check_id = 10` and another row with `check_id = 21`.

Use it with the operator `IN` to select the rows:

```
select * 
from turip_refs
where check_id in (10, 21)
  and ref_no in (
    select ref_no
    from turip_refs
    where check_id in (10, 21)
    group by ref_no
    having count(distinct check_id) = 2  
  )
```

Or, if your version of MySql is 8.0+ and there is no case of duplicate `check_id`s for each `ref_no`, then use `COUNT()` window function:

```
select check_id, name, ref_no
from (
  select *, count(*) over (partition by ref_no) counter 
  from turip_refs
  where check_id in (10, 21)
) t
where counter = 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=011cb57dda17ccde29c07c85472787e1).
Results:

```
> check_id | name  | ref_no
> -------: | :---- | :-----
>       10 | alsak | xdr   
>       21 | turin | xdr
```

Comment: OP tells: *Now i want to return records matching a certain `check_id` with similar `ref_no`*. The values 10 and 21 are an example values, not task parameters. The same about the amount of different *`check_id` with similar `ref_no`* - a pair is not a parameter, in general it can be greater.

Comment: @Akina the OP's query contains: `WHERE `check_id`=10 OR `check_id`=21`, so I think that 10 and 21 are task parameters.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM turip_refs t1
JOIN turip_refs t2 USING (ref_no)
WHERE t1.check_id != t2.check_id
-- AND another conditions
ORDER BY ref_no 
-- , another criteria
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7dfa6c3c306cb1ff9bbd0502cff03255)

Comment: I can understand the downvote without a comment. But I cannot understand silent vote to answer deletion. Especially when the fiddle shows the output correctness.